# How to start a process when available result of another process in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am developing a web application using python flask.so i realized this is much slow when this give the output.so i decided to use multiprocessing to execute two tasks simultaneously.i have separated flask framework codes and pure python codes because i am flask beginner.then i used MVC to do that thus flask framework codes in view file only.every other backed parts written in pure python.so it's nothing to do with flask actually but give the output to show in web page.

i have two main processes.

1. do some calculations and fill a list
2. do some further calculations based on 1 st process output.

My question is...

i want to run this two processes simultaneously but No2 process should not start until no1 process give output to the list (this list should use by these two processes) and N01 process not stop after give output it's also running along with no2 process. then parallel processing start when no1 process give at least one output initially. how can i do that ?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you could run them in parallel if `2` relies on `1`'s result.  Does `1` *feed* a steady stream of information to `2`?

Comment: @wwii yes. after p2 start p1 doesn't stop, it is also running further.

Answer (score 0):

These codes start two functions at the same time.

"No2 process should not start until no1 process give output to the list!" >>> use the "if" statement for this!

**code:**

```
from threading import Thread

def first_func():
    print("Jundullah")

def second_func():
    print("Ju")

def run():
    Thread(target=first_func).start()
    Thread(target=second_func).start()

run()
```

Comment: @Kalo. Under the hood, not at all, especially in Python, but you can use them to fulfill a similar abstraction.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes you are right but in here i want to execute two process same time in multi threading we are using time adjustments but in my case there are no process idle times. both processes  suppose to run same time.